# date comparison between two atomic vectors

Tags: r, date

Suppose two atomic vectors of class `Date`:

```
actual_date <- Sys.Date()
later_date <- as.Date(sub("\\d{2}$", "05", actual_date))
```

How to compare if `actual_date` > `later_date` in a way it returns a boolean?

When trying to get the comparison evaluation:

```
comparison = (actual_date > later_date)
```

> Error in charToDate(x) :
> character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Expected Output:

```
# FALSE
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working fine

```
actual_date > later_date
[1] FALSE
```